# Displaying HTML in GWT Panel

Tags: html, gwt

Is there a way to display HTML in a GWT Panel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short Answer: You can add HTML to a GWT Panel by creating an HTML widget and attaching that widget to your panel. For example...

```
HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
HTML html = new HTML("<p>This is html with a <a href='www.google.com'>link</a></p>");
hp.add(html); // adds the widget to the panel
```

Long Answer: There are a variety of ways that you can add HTML to a GWT Panel. You should start by reading the [Developer's Guide for GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuide.html). Specifically, you should read the portions on [Layout Using Panels](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html) and [Widgets](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiWidgets.html).

Comment: The problem is the exta div it creates. Any solution to avoid this extra div? I'm trying to create a raw span.

Answer (score 5):

Also, the new declarative UI stuff in GWT 2.0 saves you from having to embed HTML into your Java.

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
   Here <strong>is some HTML</strong>.
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ahhh. I was thinking about it differently. It's the widget I'm putting into the panel that needs to be formatted. Therefore if I do a

```
HTML example = new HTML(someText)
```

then add it to a panel it'll work :)

Answer (score 3):

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

RootPanel.get().add(new HTML("<b>Gwt Html</b>"));
```

you can add this HTML widget to any panel with "`panel.add(widget);`" code